# Linksys WRT54GL router as Access Pointer - router IP missing / do not know

Tags: networking, ip, router

I have a Linksys WRT54GL wirless lan router inside my network. I know that it has a static IP, but I don't know the IP address.
Is there a tool out there like QNAP QFinder (to find QNAP NAS) to find the routers IP address?

Comment: Are you connected to it?

Comment: I only have access to an WIN 7 PC - which is located in the same wired-network.

Comment: So, to be clear, it is a sibling on the network. Your PC is not plugged into it (parent/child)?

Comment: the IP of the WIN 7 PC is: 192.168.0.222 (static address) - there is a main Router with DHCP turned on (192.168.0.1). On this network (192.168.0.*) and there is the SPECIAL WIFI-ROUTER (that one I want to know the IP) connected (over one LAN-Ethernet-Port - NOT the WAN-Port). And this SPECIAL WIFI-ROUTER has a static IP (maybe 10.0.2.100 or 192.168.0.210 or 192.168.1.157 .... I don't know)

Comment: This is probably off-topic for StackOverflow to be honest. I posted my best guess at an answer, but this may be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods I can come up with (from easiest to most involved):

- If you know the network name of the router (or give it one), you can ping it to get its IP)
- Connect directly to the router and run `ipconfig` in a cmd prompt. `Default Gateway` should be the router's IP. (reminds me of this for some reason: http://bash.org/?5273)
- run `arp -a`, and look at the list of peers. One of them should be your router. As far as figuring out which of them, you can try to visit the ip in your browser. The router would have a Linksys page.
- download [nmap](http://nmap.org/) and run `nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24` (I think that would work, you will probably want to check the documentation on that.)

Comment: okay thank you - that is a solution when I can connect to the router directly and I am physically there. But what would be a solution, if I can not connect directly to the router, because I am physically not there.

Comment: I added one extra method. Please take a look at each one - I am sure one of the above methods will work for you if you are on the same network (even if not physically present).

Comment: i found the IP it is 192.168.0.105 - but I can not connect to it over HTTP to get to the admin area. Ping is possible.

Comment: You'll have to enable remote management on the router (generally a bad idea) if you want to be able to change the settings from outside its subnet. Maybe there is a way to "trust" only the parent subnet. I am not sure. But that is why you cannot perform admin functions. You'll eventually need to connect to it from inside its subnet to make those changes.